# How to file a bug against the deb file format?

Tags: deb, bug-reporting

I want to file a bug report against the deb file format that Debian and Ubuntu use as an install file format. How can I do that? Where do I file the report?

Comment: Woah, now, that sounds more like a question for Unix&Linux.  :)

Comment: How can there be a bug in a file format? You should file a bug against the package using deb files, ie.e. `dpkg`, I think.

Comment: @ByteCommander: Well, it's not exactly a bug, I want to make a feature request for the deb file format to allow a certain thing, probably in the control file.

Comment: If only we knew what the "certain thing" was....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to submit a [Debian Enhancement Proposal](http://dep.debian.net/), to propose said enhancement to dpkg. For example, the autopkgtests support is via DEP-8.